# While loop cause Tkinter canvas to not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was making a timer which is placed onto a canvas. Everything was going fine until I placed a while loop this caused my Tkinter canvas to work. Here is a simplfied version of my problem.

```
    from tkinter import *

    class Second(Frame):
        def __init__(self,master):
            super(Second, self).__init__(master)
            self.grid()
            self.TimerFrame = Frame(self)
            self.create_Timer_widgets()
            self.TimerFrame.grid()
        def create_Timer_widgets(self):
            self.canvas = Canvas(self.TimerFrame,height = 100, width = 850, bg = "light grey")
            self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
            self.canvas.create_text(400,50,text ="X")    
            self.canvas.create_text(75,50,text="N)")

            mins = 1 
            while mins > 0 :
                if len(str(mins)) == 1  :
                    self.canvas.create_text(825,50,text = "0")
                self.canvas.update() 

    root = Tk()
    x = Second(root)
    root.configure(background='light grey')
    root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code nothing happens. The shells just does nothing. After removing the while loop:

```
mins = 1
while mins > 0 :
    if len(str(mins)) == 1  :
        self.canvas.create_text(825,50,text = "0")
     self.canvas.update()
```

Which is that part of the code^^ , my code worked. Displaying everything fine. I found something online but that did not help a lot. I also removed the 'self.TimerFrame' part and that fixed my code, even with the while loop not removed, but I cannot do it this way because then my code just messes up. 
Thank for the help guys.

Comment: `TimerFrame` never gets displayed, because you never call `self.TimerFrame.grid()` - you get stuck in your loop before the code reaches that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code is that it never exits the while loop. It would be better if either -

1. you just ran the code once and removed the actual looping part,
2. if you set `mins = 0` when you wanted to exit the loop. The loop goes forever because the exit condition is never met.